# How to merge array object based on object key in PHP

Tags: php

Suppose I have an Object array like this

```
array 
  0 => 
    object(stdClass)
      public 'ID' => string '1'
      public 'DATE' => string '26/02/2018'
  1 => 
    object(stdClass)
      public 'ID' => string '2'
      public 'DATE' => string '27/02/2018'
  2 => 
    object(stdClass)
      public 'ID' => string '1'
      public 'DATE' => string '28/02/2018'
  3 => 
    object(stdClass)
      public 'ID' => string '3'
      public 'DATE' => string '29/02/2018'
```

here You can see there are two ids which are same i.e ID=1 but the dates are different. I want to merge the same id and their data like this

```
array 
  0 => 
    object(stdClass)
      public 'ID' => string '1'
      public 'DATE' => string '26/02/2018, 28/02/2018'
  1 => 
    object(stdClass)
      public 'ID' => string '2'
      public 'DA_DATE' => string '26/02/2018'

  2 => 
    object(stdClass)
      public 'ID' => string '3'
      public 'DATE' => string '27/02/2018'
```

How to merge the data so I can get two different dates into one for that same id?

Comment: What exactly is the problem, could you show us some code and explain what exactly is not working?

Comment: If I use array_unique its only depends on a single array. That's why I am asking how to do it because I don't have any idea how to merge the data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you meant the date to be an array:

```
$grouped = [];

foreach ($items as $item) {
    $grouped[$item->ID]["ID"] = $item->ID;
    $grouped[$item->ID]["DATE"][] = $item->DATE;
}

$grouped = array_values($grouped);
```

https://3v4l.org/pOio3

And if you want the date to be a string separated by a comma and not an array, then:

```
$grouped = [];

foreach ($items as $item) {
    $grouped[$item->ID]["ID"] = $item->ID;
    $grouped[$item->ID]["DATE"] = isset($grouped[$item->ID]["DATE"]) ? $grouped[$item->ID]["DATE"] . ", " . $item->DATE : $item->DATE;
}

$grouped = array_values($grouped);
```

https://3v4l.org/hiSL0

Comment: Thanks and it's working perfect. But I need to understand $grouped[$item->ID] section. Can you explain me?

Comment: @AshisBiswas its a logic in array to identify row by its `key`

Comment: Now I understand after set $grouped[1][1] when go to the same object element the grouped item [1][1] value will be same but if it's has already a date, first check it and concatenate the date with next object element keys  value. Thanks for you code